# Displaying objects which are found in C++

Tags: c++

I have a little program which stores some objects, and there is a function which should find required object if there are any matching abstraction object, returns the first found or default object. I need to display them, but when I'm using "show" function I'm getting this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'show'
```

Here is the code of main source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "object.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

using namespace std;


void fill(Inventory& i)
{
    i.add_item("object", 22, 20, "blue");
    i.add_item("object2", 25, 20, "red");
    i.add_item("object3", 40, 20, "green");

}

void show(object& item)
{
    cout << item.get_modelName() << " "
         << item.get_screenSize()<< " "
         << item.get_capacity() << " "
         << item.get_colour() << " "
         << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Inventory inventory;
    inventory.init();
    fill(inventory);


    object query1;
    query1.init("", 0, 128, "silver");
    show(inventory.find_item(query1));



    object query2;
    query2.init("object", 20, 20, "silver");
    show(inventory.find_item(query2));


#ifndef NDEBUG
    cin.get();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Inventory.h:

```
#ifndef Inventory_h
#define Inventory_h
#pragma once
#include "object.h"

class Inventory
{

public:
    // Initializes inventory for storing abstraction objects
    void init() { _count = 0; }

    // Returns the number of currently stored abstraction objects
    size_t get_count() {  return _count; }

    // Returns stored abstraction object by its index or default if index is invalid
    iPhone get_item(size_t i) { return (i <_count) ? _items[i] : iPhone(); }

    // From passed property values, creates and adds new abstraction object in an array _items
    void add_item(std::string modelName, float screenSize, int capacity, std::string colour);

    // Looks for a matching abstraction object and returns the first found or default object
    object find_item(object& query);

private:
    // The maximum number of abstraction objects that can be stored
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE{ 10 };

    // An actual array for storing abstraction objects
    object _items[Inventory::MAX_SIZE];

    // The number of currently stored abstraction objects in the array _items
    size_t _count;

};


#endif /* Inventory_h */
```

Inventory.cpp:

```
#include "Inventory.h"

void Inventory::add_item(std::string modelName, float screenSize, int capacity, std::string colour)
{
    if (_count < Inventory::MAX_SIZE)
    {
        object new_item;
        new_item.init( modelName, screenSize,  capacity,  colour);
        _items[_count] = new_item;
        _count++;
    }
}

object Inventory::find_item(object &query)
{
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < _count; i++)
    {
        object& item = _items[i];

        //for string type property
        if (query.get_modelName()!= ""
            && query.get_modelName() != item.get_modelName())
            continue;

        // for number type property
        if (query.get_screenSize() != 0
            && query.get_screenSize() != item.get_screenSize())
            continue;
        // for number type property
        if (query.get_capacity() != 0
            && query.get_capacity() != item.get_capacity())
            continue;
        //for string type property
        if (query.get_colour()!= ""
            && query.get_colour() != item.get_colour())
            continue;
        return item;

    }
    return object{};    // return the default value object (or null object)
}
```

It is my first experience in C++. That's why I might have some mistakes.
Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Make the return type of `inventory.find_item(query1)` proper.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `Inventory` class definition. Also, I'm sure the compiler actually tells you something more. When posting questions regarding build errors, please include the *complete* error message, including any informational notes.

Comment: Lastly a note about your terminology: The "main class" you show is not a *class*, it's a source file containing the `main` *function*.

Comment: I added Inventory.h and Inventory.cpp source files.

Comment: `Inventory::init`? `iPhone::init`? Did you ever hear about constructors? That's what they are for. Also what you have there is essentially a *map*. Your `iPhone` type is essentially a key, so the proper thing to do would be to implement what's required to use it as a key to `std::map` and have a `std::map<iPhone, …>` instead of the inventory class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `find_item` returns the object *by value*, and that the `show` function takes its argument *by reference*.

Since the `find_item` function can return a default-constructed object, you can't change it to return by reference, so you need to update your `show` function to be able to handle *temporary* objects (which is what the compiler will create when you do `show(inventory.find_item(query2))`).

The solution is very simple: While a reference can't bind to a temporary object, *constant* references can. So simply change the `show` function to take a reference to a constant object:

```
void show(iPhone const& item) { ... }
```

---

Of course it works for a simple `show` function like yours, which doesn't modify the argument. If you modify the argument you can't make it constant, but you can still use it with temporary objects by using something that was introduced in the C++11 standard: rvalue references ([sometimes mistakenly called universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)):

```
void show(iPhone&& item)  // Note the use of double &&
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: @songyuanyao No it doesn't, but for a function that modifies its arguments, but sometimes will be called with temporary objects (where the changes are simply discarded) there's no other way.

Comment: I see. Yes it might make sense for OP's situation.

Comment: When I used the first method it asked me to change all get_xxx() to const. So I used the second method and it works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Bestinthe `get_xxx()` should be `const`, they don't change anything, right?

Comment: @songyuanyao right now they don't change anything, but they might change later when we will use other concepts of OOP.

Comment: @Bestinthe Then consider JoachimPileborg's 2nd solution.

Answer (score 3):

`Inventory::find_item` 's return value `iPhone` is passed by value, for `show(inventory.find_item(query2));` it's a temporary object which won't match `iPhone& item` for `show()`.

Temporary object can't be bound to reference, but is ok for const reference. And `show()` doesn't change anything of the parameter, you should make the parameter type to `const iPhone&`.

```
void show(const iPhone& item)
{
    cout << item.get_modelName() << " "
         << item.get_screenSize()<< " "
         << item.get_capacity() << " "
         << item.get_colour() << " "
         << endl;
}
```

BTW: Make sure that those `iPhone::get_xxx()` are const member functions.